# MDX OLAP Calculated Measure with non aggregatable measure

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap, business-intelligence

I am currently trying to model a cube with the following dimensions : Product, Currency, Date.
The measure is ProductSaleValueInStock (all this data is stored in a denormalized SQL table).
Basically this measure cannot be summed over the Currency and Date dimensions.
My goal is to create a calculated measure on top of ProductSaleValueInStock that would allow summing over all other dimensions except for currency and date.
The MDX i am trying is like :

```
IIF( [Currency].CurrentMember = [Currency].[All] OR [Date].[CurrentMember] = [Date].[All],
      null,
      SUM({([Currency].CurrentMember, [Date].[CurrentMember])},    [Measures].ProductSaleValueInStock ]))
```

Unfortunately, when i look at my data by currency and date (Or filter using a where clause), i get null values with my expression even though the condition is False and the SUM clause returns a value if alone inside another calculated member. I am very new to OLAP so any tips would be appreciated.
Thanks